# explaining the resriction $b<a<2b$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I saw in a book that if $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle $(AB=AC)$ and the triangle is tangent to a circle in points $D,C$ and $AC$ is intersecting the circle in point $E$; $AC=a$, $BC=b$

[image]

so it has the restriction: $b<a<2b$.

Can't see how they got that restriction and hope that someone could explain.

Thanks

**EDIT**: @shaurya gupta proved that $b<a$ but the hard part is to prove that $a<2b$

Comment: Are you sure that $a<2b$ ??

Comment: that's what i saw. i can't prove it so im not sure

Answer (score 2):

This is not true without more information or inferring something from the diagram.
Suppose the circle is centred at $(1,1)$, $C=(1,0)$ and $B=(-x,0)$, with $0<x< \frac{1} {\sqrt2}$. Then $A=(\frac{1-x}2,y)$, where $y$ is unbounded for $x$ near $0$. You need some other restriction to get $a<2b$, maybe involving E or assuming that the triangle and the circle have the same height.

Answer (score -1):

We have that $AB = AC = a$. 
Clearly, $BD = BC$, because tangents drawn from common point to a circle are equal.
 $\implies BD = BC = b$.
$AB = AD + BD $
$ \implies a = AD + b.$ So $b < a$

Comment: it's not easy i think